# Use JSON To Populate Jquery Sortable From Checkbox List

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, checkbox

I am somewhat new to using JSON and am trying to populate a UI sortable list. I have one form with check box's and the next form is the sortable list. This is all on one page though, I just have jQuery fade in and outs to only show one form at a time. So I am trying to populate the list Form from the checkbox's without having to refresh the page. Here is what I got so far, I think I might be close but something is not quite right.

```
<!--Fourth Pizza Form, Select What Kinds Of Toppings-->                  
<div id="pizzatoppingtypes">
     <form method="post" name="toppingtypesform" id="toppingtypesformid">   
        <div id="main">
            <div class="example">
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Bacon"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="bacon">Bacon</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Banana Peppers"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="bananapeppers">Banana Peppers</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Black Olives"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="blackolives">Black Olives</label>
              </div>        
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Green Peppers"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="greenpeppers">Green Peppers</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Ham"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="ham">Ham</label>
              </div>    
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Hamburger"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="hamburger">Hamburger</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Italian Sausage"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="italiansausage">Italian Sausage</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Jalapeno Peppers"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="jalapenopeppers">Jalapeno Peppers</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Canned Mushrooms"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="cannedmushrooms">Canned Mushrooms</label>
              </div>             
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Fresh Mushrooms"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="freshmushrooms">Fresh Mushrooms</label>
              </div>        
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Onions"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="onions">Onions</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Pepperoni"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>
              </div>    
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Pineapple"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="pineapple">Pineapple</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Sliced Smoked Sausage"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="slicedsmokedsausage">Sliced Smoked Sausage</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Extra Cheese"/><label style="color:black; font-size: 20px;" for="extracheese">Extra Cheese</label>
              </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>    
</div>
<div><button href="#" id="btn4">Sort Pizza Toppings</button></div>  

 <!--Fifth Pizza Form, Sort The Toppings-->    
<div id="pizzatoppingsort" >
            <form method="post" name="splittoppings" id="splittoppingsid    
                <div id="main">
                    <div class="example">
                        <div>
                            <!--The First Half (Left Side) Of The Pizza-->
                            <div id="pos" width="200px">
                                <img src="images/pizzaleft.gif"/>
                                <h3>First Half</h3>
                                    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                                      <!--The Potential Moved Items Go Here-->
                                    </ul>
                            </div>

                            <!--The Whole Pizza-->  
                            <div id="pos" style="margin-left:200px;" width="200px">
                                <img align="center" src="images/pizza.gif"/>
                                <h3>Whole Pizza</h3>
                                    <ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable">

                                    <!--Javascript Function Populates This List-->

                                    </ul>
                            </div>  

                            <!--The Second Half (Right Side) Of The Pizza-->    
                            <div id="pos" style="margin-left:400px;" width="200px">
                                <img src="images/pizzaright.gif"/>
                                <h3>Second Half</h3> 
                                    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                                      <!--The Potential Moved Items Go Here-->
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
</div>

<--The Javascript -->
<script>
$('#btn4').click(function(e){   
    var selected = new Array();
    var dataObj = {};
        $("input:checkbox[name=toppingtypes]:checked").each(function()
            {
                     selected.push($(this).val());
                    dataObj.stuff = selected;
                    $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify(dataObj)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sortable3").empty();
                $.each(data.stuff, function(k, v) {
                    $("#sortable3").append("<li>" + v + "</li>");
                })
            },
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false
        });     
            });
            <!-- For Testing:  alert(selected); -->
            $('#pizzatoppingtypes, #btn4').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('#pizzatoppingsort, #btn5').fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#toppingtypesformid').submit();  
            });
});

</script>

<!--Allows Toppings To Be Sorted On Pizza Sort Page-->
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
```

If You Would Like To See More Source Code, I have a repository of it that can be found Here: https://github.com/dhierholzer/Basiconlineordering

Thanks For Any And All Input!

Comment: What is "not quite right"?

Comment: The sort list is not getting populated. It just comes up blank. I know that it is pulling data okay with $("input:checkbox[name=toppingtypes]:checked").each(function(), I just can't seem to get it to populate the Sort list.

Comment: Why are all your input IDs = "toppingtypes" ?  From jQuery documentation: "Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid." [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: I moreless copy and pasted and then forgot to change them.. Since I reference each field by name "$("input:checkbox[name=toppingtypes]:checked").each(function()" I am not sure If it would keep the function from working, none the less, thanks for bringing it to my attention.